# flatting and sorting nested arrays In javascript nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, sorting

I have an array that outputs multiple arrays  if some of the codes match they output in the same array  how do i  separate them  for example this is my array

```
[
[ [ '0011', 6, 96, '2021-08-16' ], [ '0011', 2, 4, '2021-08-17' ] ],
  [ [ '0032', 20, 26, '2021-08-16' ] ],
  [ [ '0098', 6, 246, '2021-08-16' ], [ '0098', 0, 0, '2021-08-17' ] ],
  [ [ '0093', 2, 30, '2021-08-16' ] ],
  [ [ '0051', 32, 229, '2021-08-16' ] ],
  [ [ '0053', 27, 63, '2021-08-16' ], [ '0053', 2, 38, '2021-08-17' ] ],
  [ [ '0022', 4, 2, '2021-08-16' ], [ '0022', 6, 12, '2021-08-17' ] ],
  [ [ '0067', 2, 144, '2021-08-16' ] ],
  [ [ '0166', 4, 102, '2021-08-16' ] ],
  [ [ '0015', 4, 96, '2021-08-16' ] ],
]
```

how do I get the values with two or more values in their array  and put it in so each  there are seperate within the array if that makes sense
so ideally I would like this

```
[
[ [ '0011', 6, 96, '2021-08-16' ]], 
[[ '0011', 2, 4, '2021-08-17' ] ],
  [ [ '0032', 20, 26, '2021-08-16' ] ],
  [ [ '0098', 6, 246, '2021-08-16' ],
[ [ '0098', 0, 0, '2021-08-17' ] ],
  [ [ '0093', 2, 30, '2021-08-16' ] ],
  [ [ '0051', 32, 229, '2021-08-16' ] ],
  [ [ '0053', 27, 63, '2021-08-16' ]],
  [ [ '0053', 2, 38, '2021-08-17' ] ],
  [ [ '0022', 4, 2, '2021-08-16' ]], 
  [ [ '0022', 6, 12, '2021-08-17' ] ],
  [ [ '0067', 2, 144, '2021-08-16' ] ],
  [ [ '0166', 4, 102, '2021-08-16' ] ],
  [ [ '0015', 4, 96, '2021-08-16' ] ],
]
```

or even better would be

```
[
[  '0011', 6, 96, '2021-08-16' ], 
[ '0011', 2, 4, '2021-08-17' ],
  [  '0032', 20, 26, '2021-08-16'  ],
  [  '0098', 6, 246, '2021-08-16' ],
[  '0098', 0, 0, '2021-08-17' ],
  [  '0093', 2, 30, '2021-08-16'  ],
  [ '0051', 32, 229, '2021-08-16'  ],
  [ '0053', 27, 63, '2021-08-16' ],
  [ '0053', 2, 38, '2021-08-17' ],
  [ '0022', 4, 2, '2021-08-16' ], 
  [  '0022', 6, 12, '2021-08-17'  ],
  [  '0067', 2, 144, '2021-08-16' ],
  [ '0166', 4, 102, '2021-08-16'  ],
  [ '0015', 4, 96, '2021-08-16'  ],
]
```

I tried to use flatten but adds the arrays in the same array together which isnt my desired result

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: *"I tried to use flatten but adds the arrays in the same array together which isnt my desired result"* Assuming you mean `Array.prototype.flat` or the `flatten` Underscore/Lodash near-equivalent, that's the express purpose of them, so an odd thing to reach for if you don't want a flat array.

Comment: If you're using `lodash` then use `_.flattenDepth(array, 1);` it will give the desired result.

Comment: The problem is @T.J.Crowder when I flatten the array using flat it puts  arrays in the first  element for example in to the same element when what I want to do is have every array to be a separate  element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hy try this:

```
let myarray = [
 [ [ '0011', 6, 96, '2021-08-16' ], [ '0011', 2, 4, '2021-08-17' ] ],
 [ [ '0032', 20, 26, '2021-08-16' ] ],
 [ [ '0098', 6, 246, '2021-08-16' ], [ '0098', 0, 0, '2021-08-17' ] ],
 [ [ '0093', 2, 30, '2021-08-16' ] ],
 [ [ '0051', 32, 229, '2021-08-16' ] ],
 [ [ '0053', 27, 63, '2021-08-16' ], [ '0053', 2, 38, '2021-08-17' ] ],
 [ [ '0022', 4, 2, '2021-08-16' ], [ '0022', 6, 12, '2021-08-17' ] ],
 [ [ '0067', 2, 144, '2021-08-16' ] ],
 [ [ '0166', 4, 102, '2021-08-16' ] ],
 [ [ '0015', 4, 96, '2021-08-16' ] ],
 ];




  let cleanArry = [];

  myarray.forEach(item=>{
  item.forEach(nItem=>{
    cleanArry.push(nItem)
  })
  })
  
  //this is the array that you want 
  console.log(cleanArry);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why don't you use `flat()`?

It is the same output as the accepted answer.

I post this answer just in case you miss it.

```js
const array = [
  [
    ["0011", 6, 96, "2021-08-16"],
    ["0011", 2, 4, "2021-08-17"],
  ],
  [["0032", 20, 26, "2021-08-16"]],
  [
    ["0098", 6, 246, "2021-08-16"],
    ["0098", 0, 0, "2021-08-17"],
  ],
  [["0093", 2, 30, "2021-08-16"]],
  [["0051", 32, 229, "2021-08-16"]],
  [
    ["0053", 27, 63, "2021-08-16"],
    ["0053", 2, 38, "2021-08-17"],
  ],
  [
    ["0022", 4, 2, "2021-08-16"],
    ["0022", 6, 12, "2021-08-17"],
  ],
  [["0067", 2, 144, "2021-08-16"]],
  [["0166", 4, 102, "2021-08-16"]],
  [["0015", 4, 96, "2021-08-16"]],
];

const output = array.flat();

console.log(output);
```

same output as the accepted answer.

Comment: Okay for some reason when i did it the arrays in the same element would end up as one array when i wanted each array to be separate  the other solution worked fine thanks though

Comment: @Oas, I still don't understand why would you have a different result. This answer is just a reminder.